# Cross Thread exception with async and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am calling a bunch of methods asynchronously. Somehow the release version works fine but while debugging `await task1;` gives me an exception:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'comboBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it
>   was created on"

on line `comboBox1.ValueMember = "value member";`

```
async private void CallingMethod()
{
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(TroubleMethod);
    Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Method1);
    var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2(Param1));
    //other tasks
    //other stuff

    await task3;
    await task2;
    await task1;
}

private void TroubleMethod()
{
    class1 thedata = getDBdata();

    comboBox1.DataSource = thedata;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "display member";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "value member";

    class2 thedata2 = getDBdata2();

    comboBox2.DataSource = thedata2;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "display member2";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "value member2";
}
```

`TroubleMethod()` has only one reference which is `task1`. So why the exception?

Comment: You have to update controls on the UI thread. You can use [Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to do it from a different thread.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartsNew()` takes a thread from the thread-pool and executes the method on that thread. But you can/should not access your UI controls from a different thread than the UI thread.

Comment: wrap the code that accesses the UI controls in a Dispatcher.Invoke block

Answer (score 0):

problem lies on `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Yes its true that `async` and `await` does NOT create new thread. But! `StartNew` might

what you would want to do is to make your `getDBdata2` and `TroubleMethod` async and just do

```
await TroubleMethod()
```

inside TroubleMethod do

```
await getDBdata2()
```

Comment: .. and not `void`

Comment: Thanks Steve I tried your solution. But it gives me an error on 'comboBox1.DataSource = thedata;' saying "System.ArgumentException: 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.'" I found a solution but somehow I can't post on this thread anymore.

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal that's another issue, basically your class1 has to implement IList or IListSource interface. Or you can just use a regular list instead.